# Sprite sizing in Unity

Tags: unity

I have a visual design created in Photoshop which is 1440 pixels wide and 3118 pixels heigh. I need to import the assets in Unity and achieve the same layout that's done in Photoshop. I tried playing with the Pixels per Unit setting for the sprites but didn't have any success getting the same sizing I see in Photoshop.
What I'm trying to do is, get the same horizontal layout in Unity and calculate the vertical layout manually and scale the sprites based on mobile device screen resolution.
What's the calculation method to achieve this?

UPDATE:This is what I've done so far:

Design resolution is: 1440x3118

Camera ortographic size = 8

This makes 1 unit = 390 pixels

A 100 pixel heigh sprite in Photoshop has 0.25 units in Unity

Pixel per unit should be 195 in Unity to achieve the same sizes in Unity (390 / 2 taking camera ortographic size into consideration)

Is this calculation correct? The output seems somewhat ok to me but I haven't tried this on various devices.

Comment: By the way: You can test how your game handles different device resolutions by testing the game in the Unity editor, undocking the play window and resizing it manually.